# return 2 extra columns on query with calculation

Tags: mysql

What I want to do is probably very simple, but I have a table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       price      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         30       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Which query I am using in this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE `get_info`(IN itemID VARCHAR(255), IN itemQuantity VARCHAR(255)) 
BEGIN
SELECT * from table where ID = itemID;
END
```

Now I would like the query to return 2 extra columns, with "quantity", which is procedures input "itemQuantity" and the extra column "totalPrice" which is itemQuantity*price.

So the table looks like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|----------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       price      |       quantity       |     totalPrice   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         30       |          2           |        60        |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------------|------------------|
```

I can return everything separately, but how do I combine it into one query result?

Comment: Seems obvious include the parameters in the select - am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
PROCEDURE `get_info`(
    IN in_itemID VARCHAR(255),
    IN in_itemQuantity VARCHAR(255)) 
BEGIN
    SELECT t.*, in_itemQuantity as itemQuantity, in_itemQuantity * t.price as totalprice
    FROM table t
    WHERE t.ID = in_itemID;
END;
```

Notice that I changed the names of the parameters, by prefixing them with `in_`.  This significantly reduces the chance that the parameter conflicts with an existing column name.

Comment: You may have to change IN quantity data type to int, or cast() before multiplication

Also, If you want to display price to the user in a culture-sensitive way you may want to use convert to Money type, or DECIMAL(19, 4) is a good choice

Comment: Thanks. Was pretty obvious... Just can't get used to the sql syntax.